# Can I load Office.js into an iFrame?

Tags: office-js

I'm working on an Excel Add in. For security reason, we want to load Office.js into a sandbox iframe. I see it seems working in Windows, but does not work on my Mac. I wonder is this a supported use case to load Office.js?

Comment: Could you describe a bit more?  What are the security reasons?  And are you trying to run the whole add-in in an iFrame, inside of its own Add-in sandobx?

Comment: In general we don't like referencing external javascript into our page. We either take the source code and check in and serve from our server, or we use the iframe sandboxing to load from external source.

Office.js is a loader which will load other resources dynamically. So it is not easy to host it on our server due to our current JavaScript build infra. So the best way for us is to load the Office.js into an iFrame so that it is sandbox. Then we can write a layer through postMessage to communicate with the sandbox iframe for interop.

Comment: What prevents you from checking in not just Office.js but also the other files (excel-win32-16.01.js, etc)? The Office JS Nuget package has them all...

Comment: There are couple of issues prevent us from hosting all of them with our infra without need to change the code (which doesn't seems to be allowed by the license)

Our dev infra on building these javascript resource. Our builder determine static dependencies on javascript resources and build packages automatically. So it is quite hard to support satellite strings.js files which is loaded in realtime.

And also there are some JavasScript Office.js has hard dependency on using absolute URL, the microsoftajax.js. If we want to also serve that, we have to change the code.